# Javascript (nodejs) matchmaking queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, matchmaking

I am new here and I need little help or a direction.

I need to build a simple game matchmaking queue for Counter-Strike game.

So, I need a join queue button with a alert/notification to accept the match when it's ready (10 people in queue to make a match) and if someone doesn't accept to put him on a cooldown for some time.

I am already doing a account authentication via steam openid

I will be really happy if someone points me to a right direction or to help a bit. Currently no clue what to do.

I did read all the information in google whatever I could find to point me somewhere, but nothing like mine or a projects from 5-7 years old at github.